# React, when should I use class component and when to use no class component?

Tags: reactjs, components

I am new to react, and I noticed 2 ways that components built, and wanted to know which to use when

this is the first type, seems like the logical one that I would always use

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class ConnectedForm extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {};
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form>
              <div> blah blah</div>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
const Form = connect()(ConnectedForm);
export default Form;
```

but then there is this simple looking component with no class and it's not extending the component:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return state.locations;
};

const LocationsList = ({ locations }) => (
    <ul>
        {
             locations.map(el => (
            <li key={el.id}>
               Name - {el.name}, Address - {el.address}, Coordinates - {el.coordinates}, Category - {el.category}
            </li>
        )) }
    </ul>
);
const List = connect(mapStateToProps)(LocationsList);
export default List;
```

I was wondering whats the name of each approach, and when I should prefer the simpler one over the class one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you want to use a "Class based component" for anything thats going to have logic in it and a "Functional component" if it is only displaying data or doing simple interactions which you will pass in as props or use hooks.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since [hooks were released](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) its preferred to use Functional components with hooks, which can do what class based components only could.

Comment: I mentioned that in my answer but still prefer to use a class based component when there is lots of logic, so not to have to set up hooks for every functionality I need. But in principal @Alvaro is right.